# How to prove this series about Fibonacci number: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{F_{n}}{2^{n}}=2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove this series result:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{F_{n}}{2^{n}}=2$$

where $F_{1}=1,~F_{2}=1,~F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2},~~n\geq 3$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137063/prove-that-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracf-n2n-sum-limits-n-0-i

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114800/infinite-series-fibonacci-2n and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88529/how-to-prove-the-fibonacci-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracf-npn-fr

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hint**. You may use the fact that, if

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nx^n \tag1$$

with $F_n$ the nth Fibonnacci number, $F_{n+2}=F_{n}+F_{n+1}$, then

> $$f(x)={x\over 1-x-x^2}.\tag2$$

A proof of $(2)$ may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874163/generating-functions-and-closed-form-solution-for-fibonacci-sequence/874167#874167).
Apply it to $x:=\dfrac12$.

Comment: Excellent!(+1) Thank you so much(•̀ω•́)

Comment: @EvilNebula. You are welcome.

Comment: A less efficient way is to use $F_n=(a^n-b^n)/\sqrt 5$ where $a=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$ and $b=(1-\sqrt 5)/2=-1/a$. The values $a,b$ are the solutions of $x^2-x-1=0.$ This formula  for $F_n$ is easily proved by induction on $n$, noting that $a^{n+1}=a^n+a^{n-1}$ and $b^{n+1}=b^n+b^{n-1}.$